# Wkhmltopdf works fine in the terminal but not in the php

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

When I am using wkhtmltopdf in the terminal it works fine and pdf is generating correctly.
But when I am trying to use this in the php using 'system' command, it fails and gives apache error that 'cannot connect to X-server'.
In php, I used like this.

```
 system("wkhtmltopdf $url output.pdf");
```

I tried 'exec' instead of system but giving the same problem.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a permission error if it works via command line but not PHP. Are you working locally or on a remote server? If you're on shared hosting, try contacting support to see if you have permission to call `system`, `exec`, or `shell_exec`.

Alternatively, try redirecting your standard error to a text file, maybe that will steer you a bit in the right direction:

```
system("wkhtmltopdf $url output.pdf 2> /tmp/error.txt");
```